# Keep Twitter Boostrap dropdown menu stays open on clicking toggled item

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to keep the dropdown menu stays open while clicking on toggled item.  I'm successful on keeping the dropdown menu open, but my toggled items don't work right.  The first time I clicked on the toggle item, it does what it supposes to do, but the second time I click on it, it will not toggle until I close the dropdown menu.  Could anyone give me some directions on this?

```
HTML:
<div class="span2">
  <div class="dropdown sort_main">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Sort by: </a>
    <span>Rating</span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sort" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
       <li><a id="ratings" href="#">Option1</a></li>
       <li><a id="timezone" href="#">>Option2</a></li>
       <li><a id="level" href="#">>Option3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>        
$("a#ratings").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("option_selected");  //it will not remove this class until i close menu and open it again
});

$('.dropdown-menu a#ratings').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for posting the `e.stopPropagation();` it answered my unrelated question. sorry i dont have an answer for yours.